# Why does my wired connection fail with secondary-connection-failed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I was changing my ufw rules when my wired connection suddenly failed altogether. Even after disabling ufw, every time I try to connect the wired connection it simply fails.

I am able to boot into an old 16.10 live usb and the wired connection works perfectly.

When I examine journalctl immediately after attempting to connect I get the following:

`Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1360] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (01920e80-0c39-3968-ab5e-99dbba5f8e64)
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1363] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="01920e80-0c39-3968-ab5e-99dbba5f8e64" name="Wired connection 1" pid=2481 uid=1000 result="su
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1368] device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1373] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1381] device (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1399] device (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1401] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1425] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): dhclient started with pid 3406
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev dhclient[3406]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.2 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x70f92a1a)
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev dhclient[3406]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.2 from 192.168.0.1
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1707] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   address 192.168.0.2
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1707] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   gateway 192.168.0.1
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   lease time 3600
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   hostname 'mark-dev'
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6):   domain name 'gateway'
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1708] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed unknown -> bound
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev avahi-daemon[1207]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.2.
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev avahi-daemon[1207]: New relevant interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev avahi-daemon[1207]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.2 on enp0s31f6.IPv4.
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1720] device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1726] device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1727] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp0s31f6) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1562368974.1742] policy: secondary connection 'eb2c7cac-ca3f-40c5-84b0-4ae23db66bdf' auto-activation failed: The connection doesn't exist.
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1745] device (enp0s31f6): state change: secondaries -> failed (reason 'secondary-connection-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1746] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1562368974.1748] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 06 09:22:54 mark-dev NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1562368974.1751] device (enp0s31f6): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')`

The key seems to be the secondary-connection-failed message, but I have no idea what this means or how it could have been affected by anything I changed with ufw.

I'm at a loss as to what could have caused this or what to do to resolve it.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit more research I discovered that second-connection-failed referred to the vpn I had set the network manager up to automatically connect to after successfully connecting the wired network.

I'm not sure exactly why it was failing, because the specified vpn had been correctly set up. However, I resolved the issue by running `nm-connection-editor`, entering the setup for the Wired connection, and unchecked `Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection` under the `General` tab.

This allowed my wired connection to successfully connect. I then rechecked `Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection` and selected a vpn from the drop down. Everything appears to be working now.